# Anyone can help me to integrate zephyr scale to cypress project?

Tags: cypress, jira-zephyr

I am currently switching to cypress. I am not able to get proper documentation regarding zephyr scale for integration for my cypress project.

I only found doc related with selenium integration. I have found documentation related with API as well but not able to found doc related to integration